# dynamodb batchupdate using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As per

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html d

Dynamodb does not support batchupdate only batchwrite/put is supported . But DynamoDBMapper supports batchWrite with a behaviour of UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES. Does it mean internally mapper calls single single update instead of batchupdate for UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use BatchWrite, it replaces the existing items(Not update). Even if you use DynamoDBMapper, the functionality should be the same.

According to the DynamoDBMapper [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java), `SaveBehavior` with `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES`, it ultimately calls [BatchWriteItemRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/BatchWriteItemRequest.html) iteratively in 25 batch size, which replaces the existing items.

Check the following statement in [AWS Class Reference](http://javadox.com/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.9.26/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/BatchWriteItemRequest.html) Documentation.

> NOTE: BatchWriteItem cannot update items. To update items, use the
>   UpdateItem API.

Comment: by default yes it replaces but when you set in DynamoDBMapperConfig withSaveBehavior(SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES) then also does it replaces existing item or skip the null attributes ?

Comment: Check the updated answer :), I just gone through the source code and checked whats happening internally.